# Need review for SSL support from beginning to end for HTTPListener class based server in C#

Tags: c#, ssl

This week I got a requirement for implementing a `HttpListner` based `https` server in C#.
This server worked fine for http and https based endpoints on my dev box. 
but it seems to be behaving inconsistent on other boxes and not able to locate `https` based endpoint.
For enabling SSL based endpoints I have done following things.

1. I bought a new certificate from certification authority as a pfx file with name local.xyz.com.
2. I installed it programmatically using following code:

   ```
   var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
               store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite); //Requires Administrative privileges 
               var existingCert = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, certName, false)

                   if (existingCert.Count > 0)
                   {
                       store.Close();
                       return true;
                   }

               var certificate = new X509Certificate2(certFileName, "password");
               store.Add(certificate);//Requires Administrative privileges
   ```
3. I registered the certificate to the necessary port using the netsh command as follows. this too pragmatically.

   netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:{0} certhash="xxxx" appid={application guid} certstorename=MY";
4. To make sure that my application will continue to run without admin privileges I added following code into service which runs under admin privileges. this too pragmatically.
   this service is consumed from my windows desktop app

   netsh http add urlacl "https://+:{51001}\" user = everyone";
5. I also added the certificate name into the host file so that it can be resolved against the certificate name.
   i.e 127.0.0.1 local.xyz.com

The HTTPListener server code has two prefixes added. first one is 'localhost' at port 50001 and the other one for ssl 'local.xyz.com' at port 51001.

The endpoints exposed by this server is expected to be consumed from the same machine. that is prefixes localhost or local.xyz.com will both resolve to localhost.

and prefixes are added as follows:

```
.prefixes.add('localhost",50001);
.prefixes.add("+",51001);
```

Can anyone point me for any thing which I am missing or doing wrong here so that my code will be stable and works fine for each machine and each run.

Comment: you need to clarify what behaving inconsistently means. on skimming over the parts that look fishy are messing with hosts file and the certstore. do all the machines trust the authority that issued the cert? when connecting to other machines running this do you use the ip or the name? is this failing on cert validation? does it work from within the same machine?

Comment: Thanks for quick reply Mircea.
Actually This server is expected to be consumed by a web site opened on same machine in a browser. 
moreover since its being consumed on same machine the API's will be exposed over the localhost or local.xyz.com(mapped to 127.0.0.1 in hosts file).
Now all above code discussed is working fine without any exception,
but its not able to resolve the url for https based api. When https based uri browsed from Postman restclient app in browser, i am getting 502 error code saying dns not resolved. however its working fine for localhost based api url in the same run.

Comment: so to answers all this in detail
do all the machines trust the authority that issued the cert?-- Don't Know, i am not dropping any other certificate.
when connecting to other machines running this do you use the ip or the name? - We dont connect to this from outside.
s this failing on cert validation? -No Server is starting without any exception.
does it work from within the same machine? No, it only works for http endpoints not for https. I hope i am clearly highlighted all points, please ask for any further clarification if required.

Comment: sounds like a DNS issue. try "ping local.xyz.com" and "nslookup local.xyz.com" and tell me what you see. also, what is the DNS configured to be used on the machine? is xyz.com that's part of the FQDN valid in your local network?

Comment: Hi Mircea,
You are right it is a DNS issue for sure. for the cmd ping and nslookup i was getting follwoing results:
-ping local.xyz.com-
Ping request could not find host local.xyz.com. Please check the name and try again.
-nslookup local.xyz.com-
Server:  noi-dc-01.agfahhhsks.org
Address:  171.22.0.4
*** noi-dc-01.agfahhhsks.org can't find local.xyz.com:Non-existent domain. However after getting it added to my companies local dns server i am able to resolve the issue and it started working fine. could u plz suggest what could cause it for not working even though i made entry into host file.THx

Comment: without seeing the interface configurations and the hosts files I cannot tell. but I am going to guess it has to do with the order in which name resolution happens. take a look at: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd197560(v=ws.10).aspx